# IDE for IcedCoffeeScript programming?

Tags: iced-coffeescript

What IDE can I use to develop IcedCoffeeScript code with syntax highlight and intellisense?

I tried to use Webstorm, but it does not support IcedCoffeeScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have more than syntax checking/coloring and snippets with (iced)CoffeeScript (on any IDE) because the way the language operate. So intellisense is out of game. Many environments supports autocomplete, who can help.

- [Atom Editor](https://atom.io/) has [Iced Coffee Compiler](https://atom.io/packages/iced-coffee-compiler), [syntax highlight](https://atom.io/packages/language-iced-coffeescript)(the same with sublime or other), and someone have add [snippets](https://atom.io/packages/language-ice)([or](https://atom.io/packages/language-coffee-script-on-ice)). Finaly has a very good [autocomplete](https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-plus) package by default.
- Sublime has only [syntax hightligh](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/IcedCoffeeScript)
- Bracket editor have nothing!
- same with visual studio code.

note: all editors can have different kinds of autocomplete features with or without packages(extensions).